# RxJS tricky zip two observables

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming

Having `getLastOrder()` and `getUserDetails(lastOrder.owner)` async operations. (both returns `Observable`)

Looking for fancy operator to get combined result that will include both: `[lastOrder, userDetails]` who owns that order.

P.S. doing that via temporary variables does not look pretty

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by operation? Is `A` a no arg function that returns an `Observable` and `B` an function which transforms an `Observable`?

Comment: Could you give a less abstract example of what you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: sorry, have edited question completely.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about fancy operators, but this can be solved quite easily by combining the operators `flatMap` and `map`. Also note that my functions just return dummy data but should work the same way with any observables:

```
function getLastOrder() {
  return Rx.Observable.of({owner: 'foo'})
}

function getUserDetails(owner) {
  return Rx.Observable.of({details: 'bar', owner})
}

function combined() {
  return getLastOrder()
    .flatMap(order => getUserDetails(order.owner).map(details => [order, details]))
}
```

When you think about prettyness, also think about the next guy who will read it.

Comment: Tip: when you write `.flatmap(x => doIt(x).map(y => [x,y])` it is better to separate your [resultSelector](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap): `.flatmap(x => doIt(x), (x,y) => [x,y])` as added bonus you also get acces to the indices of `x` and `y`